# Valgrind find an error which I do not understand

Tags: c, arrays, bounds

I've written a the following function

```
void x_dealiasing(int scounts, int nx, int nxd, FFT_SCALAR *u) {
    /* scounts = initial number of ny*nz modes */
    int stride_x, placeholder=0;
    int mode, i;
    for ( mode =0; mode < scounts; mode++) {
        stride_x = mode*nxd*2;
        for ( i = 0; i < 2*nx; i++) {
            u[placeholder] = u[stride_x+i];
            placeholder++;
            //printf("u[%d]= %g\n", placeholder, u[placeholder]);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the program with Valgrind and it founds an error.
The report says

```
=6084== Invalid write of size 8
==6084==    at 0x410BBF: x_dealiasing (fft_support.c:62)
==6084==    by 0x40F852: convol_trasp_1convol_trasp (convol_trasp.c:2250)
==6084==    by 0x414FAC: dnsdirect_1buildrhs (dnsdirect.c:2187)
==6084==    by 0x40EFF0: main (channel_mpi.c:3075)
==6084==  Address 0x24b09b98 is 0 bytes after a block of size 294,920 alloc'd
==6084==    at 0x4C29B7E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==6084==    by 0x40E6B4: main (channel_mpi.c:2667)
==6084==
```

Unfortunately is the first time that I use Valgrind and I've only understood that the error is in `fft_support.c:62  -> u[placeholder] = u[stride_x+i];`
But I can't understand what is the error..

Does somebody have some hints or advices?

Thanks

Comment: `placeholder` has exceeded the allocated size of `u`.  Check your arithmetic.

Comment: How many `FFT_SCALER` elements are in the block/array pointed to by `u` and what are the values of `scounts`, `nx` and `nxd`?

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge, you were right!!